# SOQL IN query from Python

Tags: python, salesforce, soql, beatbox, simple-salesforce

I'm wondering if anyone knows how to format an IN query using either beatbox or simple salesforce.  Example:

```
select id from lead where id in ('00Q3000000zLxkFEAS', '00Q3000000eODvUEAW')
```

In simple salesforce I have:

```
sf.get_sfcontacts_all(param="where Id in ({0})".format())
```

I have tried using a list, a tuple and a string in the format arg but keep getting a malformed request.

Any help, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using Beatbox and python 2.7 you should not get a malformed query. find the below code used without any errors:

```
import beatbox

"salesforceusername and password"
username = 'xxx'
password = "xxx"
token    = 'xxx'

"""conenct and authenticate"""
svc = beatbox.PythonClient()
svc.login(username, password+token)

"""execut SOQL query"""
res = svc.query("select id from lead where id in ('00Q3000000zLxkFEAS', '00Q3000000eODvUEAW')")

"""prints results in console"""
print(res)
```